# How to find the probabilities that maximize the standard deviation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, problem-solving

Consider the problem: "one dice has three faces $1,2,3$ with probabilities $p_1,p_2,p_3$ and it is thrown many times with a mean value $a$. What are the values for $p_1,p_2,p_3$ which maximizes the uncertainty consistent with the mean value $a$?"

Here I believe uncertainty should be understood as standard deviation.

So, the experiment for a single such dice being thrown has outcomes described by the random variable $X$ taking values on $\{1,2,3\}$ with probabilites $p_1,p_2,p_3$ respectively.

I believe that it all boils down to maximizing

$$\sigma^2(p_1,p_2,p_3)=E[X^2](p_1,p_2,p_3)-E[X]^2(p_1,p_2,p_3)$$

subject to the constraints

$$g(p_1,p_2,p_3)=p_1+p_2+p_3=1\quad h(p_1,p_2,p_3)=E[X](p_1,p_2,p_3)=p_1+2p_2+3p_3=a.$$

Thus it seems we should use Lagrange multipliers and solve

$$\nabla \sigma^2=\lambda \nabla g+\mu\nabla h,\\ g(p_1,p_2,p_3)=1, \\ h(p_1,p_2,p_3)=a.$$

Furthermore, it is clear that we have

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial p_i}E[f(X)]=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial p_i}\sum_j f(x_j)p_j=f(x_i).$$

so that we have

$$\nabla \sigma^2(p_1,p_2,p_3)=(1-2E[X],4-4E[X],9-6E[X]).$$

Thus we have the system of equations

$$\begin{cases}1-2E[X]&=\lambda+\mu \\ 4-4E[X]&=\lambda+2\mu\\ 9-6E[X]&=\lambda+3\mu\\ p_1+2p_2+3p_3&= a \\ p_1+p_2+p_3&= 1.\end{cases}$$

The fourth equation imposes $E[X]=a$. Hence substituting it on the first and second we can find $\mu = 3-2a$ and $\lambda = -2$.

But now this ought to be wrong. If I substitute this on the third equation I get $$9-6E[X]=-2+9-6a\Longleftrightarrow 6E[X]=6a+2$$

which is incompatible with the fourth equation which tells that $E[X]=a$.

So this method doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here? What is the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: You need a specific definition of 'uncertainty'. Because you are talking about choices of $p_i$ to do that, you must mean 'uncertainty' in the population, not the sample. // If one of the $p_1 = 1$ and the rest are all $0,$ then $\sigma = 0.$ For most purposes, I guess best to have all $p_i$ equal. For example, binomial variance $p(1-p)$ is max if $p = 1/2.$ // Maybe you would get useful ideas from Wikipedia article on 'diversity indexes'.

Comment: The conditions you derived for $p_i$'s are actually for *unconditional* interior extrema, whereas here it should be a conditional one subject to $\sum p_i=1$, $\sum c_ip_i=\frac aN$, and $0\leqslant p_i\leqslant1$. The minimum is acheived at boundary points.

Comment: I don't understand what is the meaning of "maximizes the uncertainty".

Comment: @FelixMarin I found this problem in one Statistical Physics lecture notes. If I'm not mistaken (that's at least how I'm interpreting it), by uncertainty they mean the standard deviation. So that: one experiment whose outcomes are described by the random variable $X$ is repeated a large number of times, and the values summed. One wants to find the probability distribution for the values of $X$ which maximizes the standard deviation of the combined experiment, compatible with the mean value of said combined experiment being a given value $a$.

Comment: @user1620696 Thanks. Now, I got the whole idea.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco so the point is that I should use Lagrange multipliers? Thus I should set $f(p_i) = \sigma^2(p_i)$, $g(p_i) = \sum p_i$, $h(p_i) = \sum c_i p_i$ and then solve $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g + \mu \nabla h$ with $g(p_i) = 1$ and $h(p_i) = a/N$?

Comment: @user1620696 Probably of littile use to use multipliers because $\sum c_k^2p_k$ can be seen as a quantity proportional to the distance of a $(n-1)$-dimensional hyperplane from the origin, thus its maximum is acheived at boundary points given those two constraints. However, multipliers only give interior extremum points.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco, actually the multipliers method didn't work (it could be some mistake on carrying it out, but I didn't find it). You said that the maximum is achieved at boundary points. You mean the boundary of the box $[0,p_1]\times [0,p_2]\times[0,p_3]\subset \mathbb{R}^3$? But that would mean that one of the $p_i$ is zero, right? I think I didn't understand, because this wouldn't make sense for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular example of three variables $p_i$, $i=1,2,3$, we can solve this explicitly as a linear problem. More general cases where $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ most likely will not succumb to such a simple approach.

We assume the scenario as given above, in which a random variable $X$ takes values $1,\,2,\,3$ with associated probabilities $p_1,\,p_2,\,p_3$.

---

In your question you wish to consider the probabilities such that:

1. The sum of $N$ independent samples has average $\alpha$.
2. The sum has maximal variance.

We note that since variances of independent samples are linear, we have

$$ \text{Var}(X_1 + \cdots + X_N) = N\text{Var}(X_1),$$

from which it follows that it suffices to answer the question: find the probabilities such that

1. The mean of $X$ equals $\alpha / N$.
2. $X$ has maximal variance.

That is: we can solve the question by considering just a single $X$; henceforth we drop the dependence on $N$, since this is an arbitrary constant, so just ask to find the $X$ with mean $\alpha$ and maximal variance.

---

We want that the mean is equal to some given value $\alpha \in [1,3]$ (noting that it is not possible for $\alpha$ to be outside of this interval, given that $X \in \{1,2,3\}$). Then we have

$$\mathbf E[X] = p_1 + 2p_2 + 3p_3 = \alpha,$$

and moreover we have the following constraints

\begin{align*}
p_1+ p_2 +p_3 & = 1, \\
0 \leq p_1 & \leq 1 ,\\
0 \leq p_2 & \leq 1 ,\\
0 \leq p_3 & \leq 1. \\
\end{align*}

Using the first constraint, and the expression for the expectation above we see that both $p_2$ and $p_3$ can be expressed in terms of $p_1,\, \alpha$

\begin{align*}
p_2 & = (3-\alpha) - 2p_1, \\
p_3 & = (\alpha -2) + p_1.
\end{align*}

Not all combinations $(p_1,\,p_2,\,p_3)$ generated in this way form valid probability distributions: for this we will rely on the remaining constraints: $0 \leq p_i \leq 1$, $i=1,2,3$. Reformulating each of these in terms of $p_1$ leads to

\begin{align*}
0 & \leq p_1  \leq 1. \\
1 - \frac12\alpha & \leq p_1  \leq \frac32 - \frac12\alpha, \\ 
2 - \alpha & \leq p_1 \leq 3 - \alpha.
\end{align*}

Depending on the value of $\alpha$ many of these constraints will be redundant (eg. for the second inequality, if $\alpha = 3$ then clearly the left hand side is less than $0$, which is already ruled out by the first constraint).

But most importantly, we have found a description of the system using only a single variable (since $\alpha$ is constant), and with the single (non-linear) constraint

$$\max \left( 0, \,1-\frac12 \alpha, \, 2- \alpha \right) \leq p_1 \leq \min\left(1, \, \frac32 - \frac12 \alpha, 3 - \alpha \right).$$

In fact on checking cases, we note that this simplifies to
$$\max \left( 0, \, 2- \alpha \right) \leq p_1 \leq \frac32 - \frac12 \alpha.$$

---

Turning to the uncertainty, which you describe as being the standard deviation, we note that maximizing this is equivalent to maximizing variance; moreover the variance is given to be

\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(X) & = \mathbf E[X^2] - \mathbf E[X]^2 \\
& = \mathbf E[X^2] - \alpha^2 \\
& = \left(p_1 + 4 p_2 + 9p_3\right) - \alpha^2 \\
& = p_1 + 4 \big( (3-\alpha) -2p_1\big) + 9 \big( (\alpha -2 ) + p_1 \big) - \alpha^2\\
& = 2p_1 - 6 + 5\alpha - \alpha^2.
\end{align*}
We see immediately without taking derivatives that the variance is linear (and increasing) in $p_1$, and therefore has its maximum at the largest feasible value of $p_1$.

That is, the maximal variance random variable $X \in \{1,2,3\}$ with mean $\mathbf E[X] = \alpha$ is determined by:

$$p_1  = \frac32 - \frac12 \alpha, \qquad
p_2  = 0,\qquad
p_3  = \frac12 \alpha - \frac12.
$$
In particular we see that for any $\alpha \in [1,3]$ the solution is always has $p_2 = 0$.

In terms of standard distributions, we see that for fixed $\alpha \in[1,3]$ the maximal variance $X$ is given by

$$X = 1 + 2 Y, \qquad Y \sim \text{Ber}\left( \frac12(\alpha-1) \right).$$

---

As a final addition, though not strictly a part of the question, we note that from this we can also see that the distribution with maximal variance  on $\{1,2,3\}$, is given by the case $X = 1 + 2\text{Ber}(1/2)$.

To see this we note that if $Y \sim \text{Ber}(q)$ for some $0 \leq q \leq 1$, then  $X = 1 + 2 Y$ has the same variance as $Y$, and moreover this is

$$\text{Var}(X) = \text{Var}(Y) = q(1-q),$$

and in particular this is maximized at $q = 1/2$, which is equivalent to $\alpha =2$.